# PowerShell, Exchange 2010 Addressbook

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, directoryservices

It is possible to access Exchange 2010 Addressbook from a PowerShell Script which is running on a client?
I want to access the addressbook, search by properties and work with the results.

I have not found any tutorial for the EWS and PowerShell.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("path to ews.dll")


$ExchangeService = new-object ExchangeServiceBinding

$paramName = New-Object UserConfigurationNameType
$paramName.Item = New-Object FolderIdType
$paramName.Name = "CategoryList"

$params = New-Object GetUserConfigurationType
$params.UserConfigurationName = $paramName
$params.UserConfigurationProperties = [UserConfigurationPropertyType]::ALL


$ExchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials
$ExchangeService.Url = "https://path.to.exchange/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
$ExchangeService.GetUserConfiguration($params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Exchange EWS Managed API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749.aspx

Comment: Have you looked at any of the examples on Glen Scale's blog?  He has some excellent examples on using EWS with Powershell.  http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about PowerShell, but you can accomplish this in Exchange Management Shell (EMC).  PowerShell v2.0+ can run remote sessions, so the EMC commands can be used from your clients.  Of course they'll need some Exchange rights to do this.  Conveniently in Exchange 2010, RBAC allows you to give miniscule Exchange rights to your users.  If this is not an option, you could do an LDAP query (that's what Outlook does) but I'm not sure of the exact procedure.

---

However, if it is an option:

```
1. Initiate your remote PowerShell session.  
1a. $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionURI http://FQDNofCAS/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos  
1b. Import-PSSession $session
```

After that, try one of the following:

```
1. Get-GlobalAddressList  
1b. Note the GAL you'll be using  
2. $GAL = (Get-GlobalAddressList "Default Global Address List").DistinguishedName  
2b. Replace _Default GAL_ with the output of step one.  
3. Get-GlobalAddressList $GAL | Update-GlobalAddressList  
4. Get-Recipinet -Filter {Addresslistmembership -eq $GAL}
4b. -Filter may require some tweaking to your specifics.
```

Note: See http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/address-lists-exchange-2007-part1.html for a better explanation of this.

--OR--

```
1. Get-User | where($_.RecipientType -like "*Mail*"}
```

Note: This will show all Mail-Enabled users, so it might not be exactly what you're looking for.